# Canvas doesn't draw colors with an alpha as they supposed to be drawn

Tags: android, canvas, transparent, alpha

After days of trying, I am just frustrated.

I've wanted to make a simple app that draws a color gradient from completely transparent to white on top of a background.
For testing, I just used a background with black, white and some greys.

But when I started the app to see the result I saw this:
[image: screenshot from a phone]

Some colors turn out to be darker or more colored than they should be. For example, the left bar should be completely white.

I quickly made an image that shows how it should look like:
[image: made with GIMP 2]

This is the code in my draw function:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            p.setARGB(255, (255/4*(4-i)), (255/4*(4-i)), (255/4*(4-i)));
            canvas.drawRect(canvas.getWidth()/5*i, 0, canvas.getWidth()/5*(i+1), canvas.getHeight(), p);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            p.setARGB(i, 255, 255, 255);
            canvas.drawRect(0, i*(canvas.getHeight()/256), canvas.getWidth(), (i+1)*(canvas.getHeight()/256), p);
        }
```

What am I missing? Is this just how the Canvas works? How can I fix this so that it looks like my example I made in GIMP?

Answer (score 0):

Because your algorithm is wrong.  Creating squares of a color is not the same thing as a smooth gradient.  Your method is going to have artifacting like you see above.  Instead of trying to do it on your own, use GradientDrawables which are already built into the platform.

Answer (score 0):

`(canvas.getHeight()/256)` cause precision problem.

use `float gHeight = canvas.getHeight() / 256f;` instead of `(canvas.getHeight()/256)`

full code:

```java
private Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        p.setARGB(255, (255 / 4 * (4 - i)), (255 / 4 * (4 - i)), (255 / 4 * (4 - i)));
        canvas.drawRect(canvas.getWidth() / 5 * i, 0, canvas.getWidth() / 5 * (i + 1), canvas.getHeight(), p);
    }
    float gHeight = canvas.getHeight() / 256f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        p.setARGB(i, 255, 255, 255);

        canvas.drawRect(0, i * gHeight, canvas.getWidth(), (i + 1) * gHeight, p);
    }
}
```

image compress cause some problem ,on phone everything is ok
[image: image compress cause some problem ,on phone everything is ok]

Comment: I changed my code to match it with yours but it still displays the image from above. Maybe the problem occurs because I render it differently. Is there a way for you to send me your project, maybe via E-Mail or Skype? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did nothing special, here is project https://github.com/fantasyRqg/GradientTest

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. I used a `SurfaceView`, which by default uses an RGB_565 format to color itself. The quality suffers because of this format. To change the format to ARGB_8888, which has a alpha channel, you have to add this line to your code.

`mSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);`

It was my mistake, that I didn't say that I am using a `SurfaceView` to display the Canvas. I thank all who have tried to find my mistake especially Fantasy_RQG.